# Checking if a list of tuples are the same

Tags: python, list, compare, tuples

Is there an easy way to see if a list of tuples in python are the same (same tuple in each position, where a tuple is the same if their corresponding elements are the the same)?  I know how to manually loop through the list and compare each element, but was wondering if there were any library functions that could do this?

Comment: How about `a == b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cmp() compares elements of two lists.

```
list1 = [('a', 1), ('b', 1)]
list2 = [('a', 1), ('b', 1)]

print cmp(list1, list2)
```

If we reached the end of one of the lists, the longer list is "larger." If we exhaust both lists and share the same data, the result is a tie, meaning that 0 is returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
len(list1) == len(list2) and all(a == b for a,b in zip(list1, list2))
```

That was my first guess, but I just tried the obvious and simple solution and that worked too:

```
list1 == list2
```

Comment: This has problems if inputs aren't identical lengths.

Comment: @jwilner you're absolutely right, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: But really, this is silly -- why would anyone try and reimplement the equality of sequences?

Comment: This still fails if the last items of the longer sequence are equal to the filler (None is the default).

Comment: `len(list_1) == len(list_2) and ...` but again, this should be viewed as nothing more than an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In `python 3.x`, you can check if two lists of tuples
`a` and `b` thus:

```
import operator

a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
b = [(3,4),(1,2)]
# convert both lists to sets before calling the eq function
print(operator.eq(set(a),set(b))) #True
```